# Trying to use the results from a loop and logging it to the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

I've create a loop to iterate through an array and output the result to the console, but I'm trying to reuse the results from the loop later in the file, but it keeps appearing as undefined in the console and not sure what I am doing wrong? Would someone please give me guidance on the issue.  Below is my current code.... Many Thanks in advance!! :)

```
// GET CLASS NAMES FROM THE HTML PAGE AND PUT IT INTO AN ARRAY
var allClassNames = [];
var finalClassName = "";
$('[class]').each(function(){
  $.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '),function(i,className) {
    if (className.length && $.inArray(className, allClassNames) === -1) {
        allClassNames.push(className);
    }
  });
});

// LOOPING THROUGH THE CLASS NAMES AND OUTPUTTING THE NAMES TO THE CONSOLE
var arr = allClassNames;
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}

// OUTPUT CLASS NAMES AND CSS STYLING TO THE CONSOLE
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(){
    console.log( 'className = .' + arr[i] , [$(this).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])] );
//                                   ^ WHERE I AM TRYING TO OUTPUT THE INDIVIDUAL RESULTS FROM THE LOOP
});
```

Comment: In this line `console.log( 'className = .' + arr[i]` you probably mean to get the `i` from the `each` function and you are not passing anything in it. try writing `each(function(i,v)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at this point:

```
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(){
    console.log( 'className = .' + arr[i] , [$(this).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])] );
});
```

`i` is equal to `arr.length` because it's the last value visited in the the `for (var i ...)` loop above, and so your printing something outside the range of the arr[] array.

To illustrate this:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
  // ...
}
console.log(typeof arr[i] == 'undefined') // this will print true, because at this point i == 5 (arr.length)
```

However, there is no correlation between the list of classes in arr[] and the elements you find in the DOM by those same class-names, but if what you're looking is to print the class name, then this will work:

```
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(){
    console.log( 'className = .' + $(this).attr('class') , [$(this).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])] );
});
```

Comment: great, you explained the problem very well in your answer. But where is the answer in your answer?

Comment: @Sachin as I stated in my answer, there is no correlation between the DOM elements that `$("." + allClassNames.join(",."))` will find and the array of classnames `arr[]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are don't declare the variable i in loop each:

```
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(){
console.log( 'className = .' + arr[i] , [$(this).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])] );
});
```

try this :

`var i = 0;`

```
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(){
console.log( 'className = .' + arr[i] , [$(this).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])] );
i++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you `i` variable is irrelevant in last loop: 
you can use this code to solve that:

```
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(i,v){
    console.log( 'className = .' + arr[i] , [$(v).css(['top', 'left', 'width', 'height'])] );

});
```

please notice `this` is now replace by `v`

Comment: this will have unexpected results, because here is `i` is an index to the DOM elements that match those class names, not the array of class names `arr[]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the index in your `$().each()`.

Example:

```
// OUTPUT CLASS NAMES AND CSS STYLING TO THE CONSOLE
$("." + allClassNames.join(",.")).each(function(index){
    console.log( 'className = .' + arr[index] , [$(this).css(['top',   'left', 'width', 'height'])] );
});
```

Notice the `index` variable in the anonymous function.

Just make sure to put the `index` variable in the anonymous function.

```
.each(function(index){
    console.log(index);
});
```

I hope this has given you some idea.

Here are some links that i think can help:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

https://api.jquery.com/each/